# Select sub portion of sting received from aws secretesmanager

Tags: linux, bash, aws-cli

I have multiple related secret stings in aws-secreate manager, in the same secret. I am running a aws cli command to retrieve them `aws secretesmanager get-secret-value --secret-id ...`. However the rustling  secretstring looks like this.

```
    "SecreteString":  "{\"Test1 <apple>\":\"Secret1\",\"Test2 <banana>\":\"Secret2\"...SecretN\"}",
```

I am trying to find a method so I can have a variable `wanted="Test3 <cherries>"` and the script will provide me with the resulting pair `Secret3` in this case. The real values do use the `<>` if it matters.

At this moment I have the following working, to some extent, without the variable

```
aws secretsmanager ... -query SecreteString| awk -F"${input)|~" '{print $2"~"}'|cut -d \, -f1

resulting in:
   \":\"Secret1\"
   \":\"SecretN\"}"~
```

Is there a cleaner way to do all of this?

Even if I continue to go down this path and clean up results I can't help but think there is a simpler way to get the data I need. without multiple `cut`,`awk`, or `sed` commands.

Comment: Take a look at [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) - it will be much easier to process it as a JSON object

Comment: jq looks like it would make this much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, to do it with a **single** `sed` command:

```
aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id ... --query SecretString | sed -e 's/.*'"${input}"'\\":\\"\([[:alnum:]]*\)\\".*"/\1/'
```

Agreed its ugly and may be hard to read. But it does parse the output with a single unix command instead of multiple `cut`, `awk` and `sed`

```
% export input="Test1 <apple>"
% aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id ... --query SecretString | sed -e 's/.*'"${input}"'\\":\\"\([[:alnum:]]*\)\\".*"/\1/'
Secret1
% export input="Test3 <cherries>"
% aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id ... --query SecretString | sed -e 's/.*'"${input}"'\\":\\"\([[:alnum:]]*\)\\".*"/\1/'
Secret3
% export input="Test2 <banana>"
% aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id ... --query SecretString | sed -e 's/.*'"${input}"'\\":\\"\([[:alnum:]]*\)\\".*"/\1/'
Secret2
```